# NSMenuItem with custom view does not update

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmenuitem, nsviewcontroller

I have a NSMenuItem with a custom view. However, when I want to update the first row in the menu it add the content as it is in the xib file, not as I set it.

My code: 
AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    _helper = [[Helper alloc] init];

    statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [statusItem setMenu:self.statusMenu];
    [statusItem setTitle:@"GravAccount"];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];

    _gravatarLoader = [[GravatarLoader alloc] initWithTarget:self andHandle:@selector(setGravatarImage:)];

    // Get email address
    _email = [_helper getEmailAddress];

    if (_email != nil)
    {
        [_gravatarLoader loadEmail:_email withSize:50.0];
    }
}

- (void)setGravatarImage:(NSImage*)image
{
    NSLog(@"Image loaded!");

    GravatarMenuItem *menuItem = [[GravatarMenuItem alloc] initWithNibName:@"GravatarMenuItem" bundle:nil];
    [menuItem.label setTitle:_email];
    [menuItem.imageView setImage:image];

    NSLog(@"Email: %@", _email);

    NSMenuItem *item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];
    [item setView:menuItem.view];

    [self.statusMenu removeItemAtIndex:0];
    [self.statusMenu insertItem:item atIndex:0];
}
```

GravatarMenuItem.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface GravatarMenuItem : NSViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSTextFieldCell *label;

@end
```

The outlets are linked in the XIB file on the file's owner.

This is the result:
Log:

```
2012-03-09 16:57:24.314 appName[51158:403] Image loaded!
2012-03-09 16:57:24.316 appName[51158:403] Email: Paul@******.se
```

Result:
[image: Result]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do:

```
GravatarMenuItem *menuItem = [[GravatarMenuItem alloc] initWithNibName:@"GravatarMenuItem" bundle:nil];
```

It only creates the view controller. It doesn't actually load the view from the nib. When you access the properties, they are most likely `nil` as the view has not been loaded (and the connections have not been made).

If you update your code to the following, everything should work fine:

```
GravatarMenuItem *menuItem = [[GravatarMenuItem alloc] initWithNibName:@"GravatarMenuItem" bundle:nil];
[menuItem view]; // load the view from the nib
[menuItem.label setTitle:_email];
[menuItem.imageView setImage:image];
```

Comment: Thanks alot. That really was simple, yet I didn't find it.